# Oracle SQL Developer - Disabling all constraints from schema

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints

I have two queries for disabling all constraints, but they don't seem to be working.

first one disables foreign keys:

```
select 'alter table '||table_name||' disable constraint '||constraint_name||';'
from user_constraints
where constraint_type ='R'
and status = 'ENABLED';
```

and the second disables everything else:

```
select 'alter table '||table_name||' disable constraint '||constraint_name||';'
from user_constraints
where status = 'ENABLED';
```

Now when I check the constraints with `SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS`
I can see that they all are still 'ENABLED'.
**Why is this?**
I tried commit after running the queries but to no avail.

My goal is to disable constraints from all tables with those queries.

Comment: It isn't sufficient to run the 2 **queries**, you then need to run all the `alter table` statements that these have generated!

Comment: then how do I run the alter table statements?

Comment: See my answer below.  Or you can just copy the output from the selects and paste it into the command buffer to run them.

Comment: Ohh now I understand that it actually just prints out the queries that I have to run! Hmm, but the FK query does not print anything, any idea why? The 2nd one works fine.

Comment: It sounds like either there are no 'R' constraints in your schema, or they were already disabled when you ran the query.  Try it again leaving out the `and status = 'ENABLED'` line (just to see what it finds).

Comment: This seems to print out all the FK constraints. Indeed they were disabled!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment above, it isn't sufficient to run the 2 queries, you then need to run all the alter table statements that these have generated.  However you could do it all at once using PL/SQL.  I have combined the 2 queries into one, using `order by` to process the foreign keys (constraint_type = 'R') first:

```
begin
  for r in
    ( select 'alter table '||table_name||' disable constraint '||constraint_name as statement
      from user_constraints
      where status = 'ENABLED'
      order by case constraint_type when 'R' then 1 else 2 end
    )
  loop
    execute immediate r.statement;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: can this be used to also enable the constraints back, by switching the status clause?

Comment: Yes, but then you would also change the `order by` so that 'R' constraints are done **last**.

Comment: so ```order by case constraint_type when 1 then 2 else 'R' end``` ?

Comment: @willberthos something like that, but there is no constraint type '1'. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_CONSTRAINTS.html for the full list.

Comment: @willberthos no, `order by case constraint_type when 'R' then 2 else 1 end`

Comment: @TonyAndrews do you how malignant it would be, to disable these constraints from an active production database? should the transactions be halted before disabling constraints?

Comment: @willberthos yes it would be a very bad idea to disable constraints in an active production database!  You'd need to schedule some downtime to do it.